# Filter out values that are close together in numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

For a small project, I need to filter out values that are close together (distance is given by a parameter) in a numpy array. The values in the numpy array are always sorted and every value is unique.

Let's view an example:

```py
sample_array = np.array([1, 7, 15, 16, 18, 19, 26, 33])
```

For a given distance, I want to remove all values that are too close to the preceding value. So

```py
dist = 1
# Desired result (remove 16 and 19)
result = np.array([1, 7, 15, 18, 26, 33])

dist = 3
# Desired result (remove 16 and 18)
result = np.array([1, 7, 15, 19, 26, 33])
```

Right now, I've implemented this looping over the array. Because I also have some larger arrays, I wonder whether there is a more efficient solution for this.

EDIT: For reference, this is my current implementation:

```py
it = np.nditer(sample_array[1:])
result_list = [sample_array[0]]

for i in it:
    if (i - result_list [-1]) > delta:
        result_list .append(i)

result = np.array(result_list)
```

Julz

Comment: You have an added complication here in the sequencing of this algorithm.  In your second example, it appears that 19 is *not* removed because 18 was *previously* removed by comparison with 15.  That type of primacy will likely preclude a vectorized operation that considers all relationships at once; and making a linear pass over the array with a loop may be the best you can do...

Comment: @AirSquid the best for a sorted array is to move forward from an element until you meet an element with bigger difference, but the interpreter overhead will kill such algorithm .... maybe cython or numba can do better.

Comment: @AhmedAEK I don't think that solves the sequencing issue, but it does bring up another aspect of the algorithm that is ill defined.  It also isn't obvious that is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

any implementation of this will involve a loop, now in python, this loop will look as follows:

```py
import numpy as np

def rem_dist(arr,dist):
    new = [arr[0]]
    for n in arr[1:]:
        if n - new[-1] > dist:
            new.append(n)
    return np.array(new)

sample_array = np.array([1, 7, 15, 16, 18, 19, 26, 33])
print(rem_dist(sample_array, 1))
print(rem_dist(sample_array, 3))
```

```
[ 1  7 15 18 26 33]
[ 1  7 15 19 26 33]
```

an obvious way to speed it up would be to compile it with numba or cython to machine code to get an almost 100 times faster code.

```py
import numba

@numba.njit
def rem_dist2(arr, dist):
    elements = arr
    results = np.empty(len(arr), dtype=numba.boolean)
    results[0] = True
    i = 0
    j = 1
    while j < len(elements):
        if (elements[j] - elements[i]) <= dist:
            results[j] = False
        else:
            results[j] = True
            i = j
        j += 1

    return_val = arr[results]
    return return_val
```

for 10,000 elements

```
time rem_dist per call = 0.0028135049999999996
time rem_dist2 per call = 2.32650000000012e-05
```

Comment: Thanks - thats very similar to my solution (I've added it to my question). I also switched to an iterator since it seems to be faster for numpy arrays.